# Hibernate cascade delete on a bag

Tags: nhibernate, orm

Having built most of my DAL using NHibernate, I've now discovered that the SQL Server's Cascade On Delete rules also need to be taken into account in my HBM files too.  I've been using bags for all my collections, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a cascade="delete" attribute to a bag.  I can change all my bags to sets, but that appears to mean I have changing all my IList<>s on my models to PersistentGenericSet<>s, which I don't really fancy doing.

Any advice?

Anthony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate-but-related concepts: NHibernate's cascading rules, and DB cascading.

The latter is actually configured on the `key` element so, if the FK has `ON DELETE CASCADE`, this is what the bag should look like:

```
<bag name="Children" ...>
  <key column="ParentId" on-delete="cascade"/>
  <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: This is correct but I want to point out that the on-delete setting is used when creating the database script from NHibernate. It will create a foreign key with on delete cascade. It will not cascade deletes of your objects.

Comment: Actually, it modifies the behavior of NHibernate, because it's now aware of the existence of the *on delete cascade* behavior so, if you have `cascade="all"`, it will rely on the DB to do it instead of deleting child objects one by one.

Comment: Just tried that and I get the following error:

Only inverse one-to-many associations may use on-delete="cascade"

Comment: Yes, you need to make the association bidirectional (Children must have a reference to Parent) and put `inverse="true"` in the bag.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a cascade attribute to a bag mapping. The [documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6%282E%292%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Mapping_a_Collection) lists several options for the attribute `cascade="all|none|save-update|delete|all-delete-orphan"`. The most commonly used option for a one-to-many relationship is `all-delete-orphan`. Setting cascade to this value will cause all database operations to be cascaded to the collection and child objects will be deleted if they are removed from the collection (orphaned).

Database cascades are similar but do not offer the ability to automatically delete an orphaned child record. Setting the cascade option in NHibernate and in the database is somewhat redundant but may be useful if you have other systems accessing the database directly.