# Cascade=delete doesn't delete related entities

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, cascade

I do have 2 entities:
 1. User
 2. Limits

User has a set of limits, so one-to-many relation is present. I do have a cascade type set to `delete`, so when `User` is deleted, all corresponding limits should be deleted as well.

```
<bag name="limits" cascade="delete">
   <key column="USER_ID"/>
   <one-to-many class="com.mac.kom.modules.limits.models.LimitsModel" />
</bag>
```

When I try to delete the `User` I do get an error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("DB"."LIMITS"."USER_ID") to NULL
```

Any clues?

Comment: maybe the accepted answer to this question is also the answer to your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728160/hibernate-cascade-delete-on-a-bag

(don't forget the inverse="true" as mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer)

Comment: Are you sure you got a `ON DELETE CASCADE` within the DB foreign key specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cascade `delete-orphan`.
`delete` tries to break the link between the both entities by clearing the FK field.
`delete-orphan` won't authorize having some `LimitsModel` without `User` and thus will delete the related `LimitsModel` record.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <bag name="limits">
       <key column="USER_ID" on-delete="cascade"/>
       <one-to-many class="com.mac.kom.modules.limits.models.LimitsModel" />
    </bag>
```